# Appening to Subject and Send message Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a macro that will add some text into the subject of a message and then send the message. I ahve created a button on the ribbon that the user will click to add (Secure) into the subject line and send the message.

I'm using the following which I've put together from several sources I found online.

```
Sub InsertSubject()

Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem

'Get the currently open message'

Set objMsg = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

objMsg.Subject = CurrentItem.Subject & "(Secure) "

'Destroy the object to avoid memory leaks'
objMsg.Send
Set objMsg = Nothing


End Sub
```

when I run this I get a Run-time error 424 Object Required. It appears to have an issue with the following line

```
objMsg.Subject = CurrentItem.Subject & "(Secure) "
```

If I remove the CurrentItem.Subject, the code works but obviously just replaces what ever subject with (Secure).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are intending to do  `objMsg.Subject = objMsg.Subject & "(Secure) "`.

Note that you are trying to use `CurrentItem` which is not necessarily the same as `Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem`. I'm not that familiar with Outlook object model but I bet `CurrentItem` when called on it's own is not valid.